# Spring Boot Maven plugin: Cannot override arguments set in pom.xml

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I am using the 2.7.4 version of the Spring Boot Maven plugin, and am puzzled about the behavior of `arguments` set in the `pom.xml`. Once there, it seems they cannot be overriden by specifying some on the command line.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-run-parameters-details-commandlineArguments)

> Arguments from the command line that should be passed to the application. Use spaces to separate multiple arguments and make sure to wrap multiple values between quotes. When specified, takes precedence over #arguments.

If I have this in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<configuration>
  <arguments>
    <argument>--oh_hello=there</argument>
  </arguments>
</configuration>
```

Then I cannot override this by for example using `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--hello=world"`.

The arguments seen when the Spring applications starts are stuck at what is specified in `pom.xml`. I expect to be able to override this. Am I misunderstanding, or is this a bug?

Full example on [GitHub](https://github.com/smurf667/spring-boot-maven-argument-precedence).

Comment: In your pom.xml file, the <argument> element sets the property name `oh_hello`, but the command line sets a different property name `hello`.

Comment: @ChinHuang yes, that is on purpose. The point is: Running `mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--hello=world"` outputs `--oh_hello=there` - that's not what I expect. My command line is ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As counter-intuitive as it may seem, it's conventional for a Maven plugin to behave in this way, with configuration in the `pom.xml` taking precedence over command-line configuration.

The reference documentation for Spring Boot's Maven plugin [recommends using a project property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.4/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using.overriding-command-line) to allow a setting to be configured on the command line. In your case, that would look something like this:

```xml
<properties>
    <run.arguments>--hello=there</run.arguments>
</properties>

<configuration>
  <arguments>
    <argument>${run.arguments}</argument>
  </arguments>
</configuration>
```

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--hello=world"
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Still looks awkward to me, but if that's by design so be it. Thanks again!